# BinaryTree traversed in postorder (DFS), iteratively

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search

I was given this coding question for a technical interview:

> Given a binary tree, implement a method to populate the list
>   post_ordered_list with the data of the nodes traversed in postorder,
>   iteratively.
>
> For example, given that a binary tree traversing items:
>
> Items in-order: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>
> Items post-order: [1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 4]

I implemented the following binary tree class and it seems to pass all the tests. [Here's a gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/Jeffchiucp/5a12e5533b77dae97d3c0271fb3d7f4f).

```
#!python
from queue import LinkedQueue, DeQueue
from collections import deque

class BinaryTreeNode(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        """Initialize this binary tree node with the given data."""
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this binary tree node."""
        return 'BinaryTreeNode({!r})'.format(self.data)

    def is_leaf(self):
        """Return True if this node is a leaf (has no children)."""
        # Check if both left child and right child have no value
        return self.left is None and self.right is None

    def is_branch(self):
        """Return True if this node is a branch (has at least one child)."""
        # Check if either left child or right child has a value
        return not self.is_leaf()

    def height(self):
        """Return the height of this node (the number of edges on the longest
        downward path from this node to a descendant leaf node).
        Best and worst case running time: O(N) under what conditions?"""

        # Base case
        if self.is_leaf():
            return 0
        # Return one more than the greater of the left height and right height
        return calculate_height_recursively(node)


class BinarySearchTree(object):
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        """Initialize this binary search tree and insert the given items."""
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
        if items is not None:
            for item in items:
                self.insert(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of this binary search tree."""
        return 'BinarySearchTree({} nodes)'.format(self.size)

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if this binary search tree is empty (has no nodes)."""
        return self.root is None

    def height(self):
        """Return the height of this tree (the number of edges on the longest
        downward path from this tree's root node to a descendant leaf node).
        n; going to go through everything"""
        #  Check if root node has a value and if so calculate its height
        return self.root.height()

    def contains(self, item):
        """Return True if this binary search tree contains the given item.
        log(n): it's going to traverse based on height, which is log(n) """
        # Find a node with the given item, if any
        node = self._find_node(item)
        # Return True if a node was found, or False
        return node is not None

    def items_post_order(self):
        """Return a post-order list of all items in this binary search tree."""
        items = []
        if not self.is_empty():
            # Traverse tree post-order from root, appending each node's item
            self._traverse_post_order_iterative(self.root, items.append)
        # Return post-order list of all items in tree
        return items

    def _traverse_post_order_iterative(self, node, visit):
        """Traverse this binary tree with iterative post-order traversal (DFS).
        Start at the given node and visit each node with the given function.
        Running time: O(n)
        Memory usage: Half of the tree. It goes down one half before another
        """
        # Traverse post-order without using recursion (stretch challenge)
        stack = DeQueue()
        # It was this, or make sure visit's len is same as the tree
        while True:
            # If the node is valid, grab right and left
            while node:
                if node.right:
                    stack.enqueue_front(node.right)
                stack.enqueue_front(node)
                node = node.left
            # If it's null, start dequeues
            else:
                node = stack.dequeue_front()
                if node.right and node.right == stack.front():
                    stack.dequeue_front()
                    stack.enqueue_front(node)
                    node = node.right
                else:
                    # Put that in the visit. 
                    # print(stack.list, visit, "\n\n")
                    visit(node.data)
                    node = None

            if stack.length() == 0:
                break
            # print(stack.list, visit, "\n\n")
        return visit




def test_binary_search_tree():
    # Create a complete binary search tree of 3, 7, or 15 items in level-order
    # items = [2, 1, 3]
    items = [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
    #items = [8, 4, 12, 2, 6, 10, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
    print('items: {}'.format(items))

    tree = BinarySearchTree()
    print('tree: {}'.format(tree))
    print('root: {}'.format(tree.root))

    print('\nInserting items:')
    for item in items:
        tree.insert(item)
        print('insert({}), size: {}'.format(item, tree.size))
    print('root: {}'.format(tree.root))

    print('\nSearching for items:')
    for item in items:
        result = tree.search(item)
        print('search({}): {}'.format(item, result))
    item = 123
    result = tree.search(item)
    print('search({}): {}'.format(item, result))

    print('\nTraversing items:')
    print('items in-order:    {}'.format(tree.items_in_order()))
    print('items pre-order:   {}'.format(tree.items_pre_order()))
    print('items post-order:  {}'.format(tree.items_post_order()))
    print('items level-order: {}'.format(tree.items_level_order()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_binary_search_tree()
```

Unit test:

```
#!python

from binarytree import BinaryTreeNode, BinarySearchTree
import unittest


class BinaryTreeNodeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_items_post_order_with_3_strings(self):
        # Create a complete binary search tree of 3 strings in level-order
        items = ['B', 'A', 'C']
        tree = BinarySearchTree(items)
        # Ensure the post-order traversal of tree items is ordered correctly
        assert tree.items_post_order() == ['A', 'C', 'B']

    def test_items_post_order_with_7_numbers(self):
        # Create a complete binary search tree of 7 items in level-order
        items = [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7]
        tree = BinarySearchTree(items)
        # Ensure the post-order traversal of tree items is ordered correctly
        assert tree.items_post_order() == [1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 4]




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```